Fastapi on GCP cloud run not killing timeout request
we have a simple fastapi application deployed on GCP cloud run, The cloud run has a timeout of 15s but sometimes the downstream API call done by fastapi exceed this time.
We are experiencing that once the 15s of cloud run timeout is reached the API call is closed correctly from the perspective of the client but looking at the logs the fastapi request is not killed and still processing till normal finish of the process. We setup a timeout on the downstream API instead relying on the cloud run timeout but is a strange behavior.
Any idea of what may be the issue?

According to the documentation of Cloud Run services, the container instance that served the request is not terminated after request end (request timeout).
So if you want to terminate the proceess you should set timeout in Cloud Run and in your application code

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

That's the normal behavior. What's your concern?

To elaborate, one instance can serve more than one HTTP request at the same time (using async or threads), so cloud run can't just kill it for a single timeout. And since cloud run has no interaction with your app code (it only sees a docker container listening to a port), it can't do anything to terminate the code running a specific request.So as others have said, this is the expected behaviour. Of you need the request to terminate, you need to implement some kind of timeout in your code.
